# Incomplete large CSV import using fread in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm using fread within R to import a number of large CSV files to create a summary file to take further for analysis. When plotting the summarised data there are a few time points (each CSV represents a month of data) which appear low and out of trend. Looking further into the problem it seems that fread isn't importing the full file and halting.

I've tried fread, countLines and read_csv all to no success. In the example below

data from https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/practice-level-prescribing-data/presentation-level-march-2013
and https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/practice-level-prescribing-data/gp-practice-prescribing-presentation-level-data-april-2013 - files are ~1.4GB each

For the two files below - T201303PDPI+BNF.CSV is the incomplete file and T201304PDPI+BNF.CSV is a complete file

I've included the error message received in the comments of the code below:

```r
library(data.table)
library(R.utils)
library(readr)

prescribing = fread("T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV")
# Discarded single-line footer: <<Q34,5PF,M87013,21020001190    ,Coloplast SpeediCath Compact Fle Size 8-,0000001,000>>
prescribing2 = fread("T201304PDPI+BNFT.CSV")

countLines("T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV")
# [1] 4427688
# attr(,"lastLineHasNewline")
# [1] FALSE
countLines("T201304PDPI+BNFT.CSV")
# [1] 10024499
# attr(,"lastLineHasNewline")
# [1] TRUE

prescribing = read_csv("T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV")
# row col   expected        actual                   file
# 4427687 NIC            embedded null 'T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV'
prescribing2 = read_csv("T201304PDPI+BNFT.CSV")
```

I would like to keep using fread to import the data (it's fast), but I can't work out how to import the full file and ignore the embedded null. Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT:

```r
prescribing = fread("T201304PDPI+BNFT.CSV", verbose = TRUE)
omp_get_num_procs()==4
R_DATATABLE_NUM_PROCS_PERCENT=="" (default 50)
R_DATATABLE_NUM_THREADS==""
omp_get_thread_limit()==2147483647
omp_get_max_threads()==4
OMP_THREAD_LIMIT==""
OMP_NUM_THREADS==""
data.table is using 2 threads. This is set on startup, and by setDTthreads(). See ?setDTthreads.
RestoreAfterFork==true
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
[01] Check arguments
  Using 2 threads (omp_get_max_threads()=4, nth=2)
  NAstrings = [<<NA>>]
  None of the NAstrings look like numbers.
  show progress = 1
  0/1 column will be read as integer
[02] Opening the file
  Opening file T201304PDPI+BNFT.CSV
  File opened, size = 1.298GB (1393405361 bytes).
  Memory mapped ok
[03] Detect and skip BOM
[04] Arrange mmap to be \0 terminated
  \n has been found in the input and different lines can end with different line endings (e.g. mixed \n and \r\n in one file). This is common and ideal.
[05] Skipping initial rows if needed
  Positioned on line 1 starting: << SHA,PCT,PRACTICE,BNF CODE,BNF>>
[06] Detect separator, quoting rule, and ncolumns
  Detecting sep automatically ...
  sep=','  with 100 lines of 11 fields using quote rule 0
  Detected 11 columns on line 1. This line is either column names or first data row. Line starts as: << SHA,PCT,PRACTICE,BNF CODE,BNF>>
  Quote rule picked = 0
  fill=false and the most number of columns found is 11
[07] Detect column types, good nrow estimate and whether first row is column names
  Number of sampling jump points = 100 because (1393405359 bytes from row 1 to eof) / (2 * 13900 jump0size) == 50122
  Type codes (jump 000)    : AAAAA577552  Quote rule 0
  Type codes (jump 100)    : AAAAA577552  Quote rule 0
  'header' determined to be true due to column 6 containing a string on row 1 and a lower type (int32) in the rest of the 10050 sample rows
  =====
  Sampled 10050 rows (handled \n inside quoted fields) at 101 jump points
  Bytes from first data row on line 2 to the end of last row: 1393405220
  Line length: mean=139.00 sd=0.02 min=137 max=139
  Estimated number of rows: 1393405220 / 139.00 = 10024513
  Initial alloc = 11026964 rows (10024513 + 9%) using bytes/max(mean-2*sd,min) clamped between [1.1*estn, 2.0*estn]
  =====
[08] Assign column names
[09] Apply user overrides on column types
  After 0 type and 0 drop user overrides : AAAAA577552
[10] Allocate memory for the datatable
  Allocating 11 column slots (11 - 0 dropped) with 11026964 rows
[11] Read the data
  jumps=[0..1328), chunk_size=1049250, total_size=1393405220
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
Read 10024498 rows x 11 columns from 1.298GB (1393405361 bytes) file in 01:23.504 wall clock time
[12] Finalizing the datatable
  Type counts:
         1 : bool8     '2'
         3 : int32     '5'
         2 : float64   '7'
         5 : string    'A'
=============================
   0.018s (  0%) Memory map 1.298GB file
   0.224s (  0%) sep=',' ncol=11 and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection using 10050 sample rows
   0.901s (  1%) Allocation of 11026964 rows x 11 cols (0.739GB) of which 10024498 ( 91%) rows used
  82.362s ( 99%) Reading 1328 chunks (0 swept) of 1.001MB (each chunk 7548 rows) using 2 threads
   +   79.434s ( 95%) Parse to row-major thread buffers (grown 0 times)
   +    2.817s (  3%) Transpose
   +    0.111s (  0%) Waiting
   0.000s (  0%) Rereading 0 columns due to out-of-sample type exceptions
  83.504s        Total

prescribing = fread("T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV", verbose = TRUE)
omp_get_num_procs()==4
R_DATATABLE_NUM_PROCS_PERCENT=="" (default 50)
R_DATATABLE_NUM_THREADS==""
omp_get_thread_limit()==2147483647
omp_get_max_threads()==4
OMP_THREAD_LIMIT==""
OMP_NUM_THREADS==""
data.table is using 2 threads. This is set on startup, and by setDTthreads(). See ?setDTthreads.
RestoreAfterFork==true
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
[01] Check arguments
  Using 2 threads (omp_get_max_threads()=4, nth=2)
  NAstrings = [<<NA>>]
  None of the NAstrings look like numbers.
  show progress = 1
  0/1 column will be read as integer
[02] Opening the file
  Opening file T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV
  File opened, size = 1.295GB (1390238802 bytes).
  Memory mapped ok
[03] Detect and skip BOM
  Last byte(s) of input found to be 0x00 (NUL) and removed.
[04] Arrange mmap to be \0 terminated
  \n has been found in the input and different lines can end with different line endings (e.g. mixed \n and \r\n in one file). This is common and ideal.
  File ends abruptly with '0'. Final end-of-line is missing. Using cow page to write 0 to the last byte.
[05] Skipping initial rows if needed
  Positioned on line 1 starting: << SHA,PCT,PRACTICE,BNF CODE,BNF>>
[06] Detect separator, quoting rule, and ncolumns
  Detecting sep automatically ...
  sep=','  with 100 lines of 11 fields using quote rule 0
  Detected 11 columns on line 1. This line is either column names or first data row. Line starts as: << SHA,PCT,PRACTICE,BNF CODE,BNF>>
  Quote rule picked = 0
  fill=false and the most number of columns found is 11
[07] Detect column types, good nrow estimate and whether first row is column names
  Number of sampling jump points = 100 because (615448576 bytes from row 1 to eof) / (2 * 13900 jump0size) == 22138
  Type codes (jump 000)    : AAAAA577552  Quote rule 0
  A line with too-few fields (7/11) was found on line 50 of sample jump 100. Most likely this jump landed awkwardly so type bumps here will be skipped.
  Type codes (jump 100)    : AAAAA577552  Quote rule 0
  'header' determined to be true due to column 6 containing a string on row 1 and a lower type (int32) in the rest of the 10049 sample rows
  =====
  Sampled 10049 rows (handled \n inside quoted fields) at 101 jump points
  Bytes from first data row on line 2 to the end of last row: 615448437
  Line length: mean=139.00 sd=0.00 min=139 max=139
  Estimated number of rows: 615448437 / 139.00 = 4427687
  Initial alloc = 4870455 rows (4427687 + 9%) using bytes/max(mean-2*sd,min) clamped between [1.1*estn, 2.0*estn]
  =====
[08] Assign column names
[09] Apply user overrides on column types
  After 0 type and 0 drop user overrides : AAAAA577552
[10] Allocate memory for the datatable
  Allocating 11 column slots (11 - 0 dropped) with 4870455 rows
[11] Read the data
  jumps=[0..586), chunk_size=1050253, total_size=615448437
  Restarting team from jump 585. nSwept==0 quoteRule==1
  jumps=[585..586), chunk_size=1050253, total_size=615448437
  Restarting team from jump 585. nSwept==0 quoteRule==2
  jumps=[585..586), chunk_size=1050253, total_size=615448437
  Restarting team from jump 585. nSwept==0 quoteRule==3
  jumps=[585..586), chunk_size=1050253, total_size=615448437
Read 4427686 rows x 11 columns from 1.295GB (1390238802 bytes) file in 00:03.479 wall clock time
[12] Finalizing the datatable
  Type counts:
         1 : bool8     '2'
         3 : int32     '5'
         2 : float64   '7'
         5 : string    'A'
=============================
   0.079s (  2%) Memory map 1.295GB file
   0.614s ( 18%) sep=',' ncol=11 and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection using 10049 sample rows
   0.526s ( 15%) Allocation of 4870455 rows x 11 cols (0.327GB) of which 4427686 ( 91%) rows used
   2.260s ( 65%) Reading 586 chunks (0 swept) of 1.002MB (each chunk 7555 rows) using 2 threads
   +    0.661s ( 19%) Parse to row-major thread buffers (grown 0 times)
   +    1.576s ( 45%) Transpose
   +    0.023s (  1%) Waiting
   0.000s (  0%) Rereading 0 columns due to out-of-sample type exceptions
   3.479s        Total
Warning message:
In fread("T201303PDPI+BNFT.CSV", verbose = TRUE) :
  Discarded single-line footer: <<Q34,5PF,M87013,21020001190    ,Coloplast SpeediCath Compact Fle Size 8-,0000001,000>>
```

Comment: can you add ``verbose = TRUE`` and post the result in your post please?

Comment: I've updated the original question with the verbose output at the end

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to get rid of nul characters then try something like this which assumes `tr` is on your PATH.  You may need to modify it slightly depending on your shell.

```
fread(cmd = "tr -d '\\000' < inputfile")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - is there a way to do this within Windows without installing something like CoreUtil?

Comment: Rtools, which is needed anyways to build R packages includes `tr`.  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/